# QtCreator + MPI on windows

Tags: qt, mpi

I installed newest Qt 5.3.0 on my windows machine with QtCreator and minGW 32 bit.

Does anyone know how to make it work with MPI (MS-MPI)?

I can locate mpiexec command but not the compiler.

Edit: MPI works when using old windows OpenMPI build with Visual Studio installed (as mpic++ looks for cl.exe from VC compiler suite).

Comment: The compile command with MPI is `mpicc` or `mpifc` usually.

Comment: True, but those commands are not in Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin directory (where mpiexec is located). They are also not in the $PATH